# optmization methods for relay co-ordination

Tags: relay, protection

I was going through various resources about relay co-ordination methods. In some of the material, a very straightforward method is provided for calculating PMS and TMS. On the other hand few articles emphasized use of meta-heurestic algorithms to arrive at the vale of PMS and TMS. I wanted to know under what circumstances, will I have to use optimization algorithms?

Comment: [PMS.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premenstrual_syndrome) You probably don't mean that. It often helps to spell out acronyms the first time you use them.

Comment: There are always tradeoffs. The protection algorithm needs to have experience built into it to determine the threshold and sensitivity to prevent loss of equipment, instability to the network and then temporary loss of service. Determining the cost factors is unique for each threshold of doing “something”  like localizing a fault must have some deterministic and experience based algorithms. No one solution works every time to minimize costs of doing something or waiting. Thus historical experience is needed for each algorithm to use meta-heuristic solutions. As in No Free Lunch. (NFL)